# sphinx `maximum_signature_line_length` doesn't work consistently

Tags: python-sphinx

I have several classes with the same function signature:

```py
def transform(self, df: pl.DataFrame, /) -> pl.DataFrame: ...
```

In some of these classes, when sphinx builds the docs, the signature appears on one line:

```
transform(df: DataFrame, /) → DataFrame
```

whereas sometimes it appears split across lines:

```
transform(
df: DataFrame,
/,
) → DataFrame
```

Here is my sphinx config:

```
extensions = [
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx.ext.autosummary",
    "sphinx.ext.doctest",
    "sphinx.ext.githubpages",
    "numpydoc",
]

templates_path = ["_templates"]
exclude_patterns = []
maximum_signature_line_length = 105

autoclass_content = "both"
numpydoc_show_class_members = False
autosummary_generate = True
default_role = "code"

html_theme = "pydata_sphinx_theme"
html_static_path = ["_static"]
html_css_files = ["css/custom.css"]  # relative to html_static_path
html_show_sourcelink = False
```

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use [`python_maximum_signature_line_length`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/zh-cn/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-python_maximum_signature_line_length)?